# Automate Perl bash script, but only run it if there are files or folders in a directory

Tags: bash, perl

I got a script that was written for me to execute automatically every day at a specific time using Cron.

The script moves files to an new location, fixes permissions, creates a folder in the new location with a date and timestamp and the name of the person that ran the script.

I would like the script to first check if there are any files or folders in a specific location before executing there rest of the script otherwise I end up with many empty folders.

Running the cronjob is the easy part, adding the "check for any files" functionality I trying to figure out. Also the script requires the input of a name when running the script, this is obviously not necessary when running the script automatically. Some help or pointing in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Thanks Bas

See below current script.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$numArgs = $#ARGV + 1;

if ($numArgs != 1)
{
        print("\nUsage :  _2_JOBS_FINISHED <folder name>\n");
        print("NOTE: no spaces in the folder name please!!!!\n");
        print("EXAMPLE: JOBS_FINISHED Clicks_Part1\n");
        exit;
}

use Time::localtime;

$tm = localtime;
($DAY, $MONTH, $YEAR, $HOUR, $MINUTE) = ($tm->mday, $tm->mon+1, $tm->year+1900, $tm->hour, $tm->min);

$myHours = sprintf("%02d",$HOUR);
$myMins = sprintf("%02d",$MINUTE);
$myDay = sprintf("%02d",$DAY);
$myMonth = sprintf("%02d",$MONTH);
$myYear = $YEAR;

$mySTAMP = "$myDay$myMonth$myYear$myHours$myMins";

$IN_DIR="/data/Raid/Jobs/_2_JOBS_FINISHED";
$OUT_DIR="/data/Raid/LTO_Pending/LTO_Jobs_Pending/$mySTAMP\_$ARGV[0]";
#print($OUT_DIR."\n");
$move_cmd="mv $IN_DIR $OUT_DIR";
#print "$move_cmd\n";
system($move_cmd);
$new_cmd = "mkdir /data/Raid/Jobs/_2_JOBS_FINISHED";
system($new_cmd);
$fix_cmd = "chown -R root.samba /data/Raid/Jobs/_2_JOBS_FINISHED";
system($fix_cmd);
$fix_cmd = "chmod -R 777 /data/Raid/Jobs/_2_JOBS_FINISHED";
system($fix_cmd);
```

Comment: See [opendir](http://p3rl.org/opendir) and [readdir](http://p3rl.org/readdir) on how to check for files in a directory.

Comment: Some general advice: Always `use strict;` and `use warnings;` in scripts. Use [`File::Copy`](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Copy) functions, [`mkdir`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/mkdir), [`chown`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chown), [`chmod`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chmod)  etc. instead of shelling out to an external program like you're writing a shell script.

Comment: @Bastien: I personally find it often easier to use [globbing](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob) in Perl instead of opendir/readdir, but this is a matter of taste. BTW: What is a _Perl bash_ script? I don't quite understand the title of your question.

Comment: File::Copy is broken in various ways around retaining permissions and attributes,

Answer (score 1):

You can do all of this in Perl. You are:

- renaming a directory (`rename`)
- creating a new directory (`mkdir` or File::Path's `make_path` for multi-level stuff).
- since the new directory is empty, you don't need the `-R` (recursive switch), so Perl's `chmod` and `chown` are capable.

If you want to check for files, a `glob` in the target dir probably does the trick. If you get some files back, it's not empty. Adjust the glob for patterns that match the files you are interested in:

```
 my @files = glob( "$old_dir/*" );
 exit unless @files;
```